# How to write scripts that can run in bash and csh?

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but is there a way to write shell scripts that can be interpreted by both the Bourne shell as well as C shell? I want to avoid simply checking for the shell and running a shell-specific code. If this is possible, are there any guides on how to do it?

I have always written my scripts for Bourne shell syntax, and I know next to nothing about csh, so this may be a stupid question. I have Google'd for the differences between shells, but there is little information (as far as I can tell) on its implications for scripting.

Comment: This is like asking if one script can run in Perl and Python.  Bash and Csh are different languages.

Comment: [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script is simple a suggest using:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

This shell is (almost?) always available.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write a single text that is a valid program in multiple languages (in fact there's one on one of the SO error pages), but these things are almost never useful—they are mere curiosities, just done to show off cleverness.

What Unix does provide, which is quite useful, is a way to *guarantee* the language of a script, regardless of what shell (or other program) is used to invoke the script.  That is the so-called "sharp-bang" syntax.  So you pick your favorite shell (I strongly prefer Bourne shell to C shell, and `file /usr/bin/* | grep shell` agrees with me), and then you write

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
print "I am running as Bourne shell no matter what your login shell is!"
```

Sometimes it is useful to write something a little more sophisticated; I have several scripts that begin with

```
#/usr/bin/env lua5.1
```

you could also do this with perl, python, ruby, ...

Answer (score 0):

you can try reading [this book](http://tinyurl.com/y277yef). otherwise, learn to use a language like Python or Perl. Its basic programming syntax, eg flow control, data structures, loops are almost all standard across older and newer versions.